# execute testcontainer integration test in gitlab pipeline

Tags: image, docker, maven, gitlab, testcontainers

I'm quite new to GitLab and docker, I have a pipeline that consists of several steps

for maven build, junit test stages I use
`image: maven:3-jdk-8` - and add appropriate maven commands in the script section

for docker build and deploy stage I use
`image: docker:latest` - and add appropriate docker commands in the script section

Now - I want to include integration tests based on testcontainers which means I need to execute at least some docker commands and mvn command. Then none of the above-mentioned images is appropriate and some part of my script fails. docker: command not found or mvn: command not found.

Does it mean that I must build and deploy to docker hub my own image that includes required dependencies? Looked for such an image but haven't found it. Or maybe is there a simpler solution? Thanks for any answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the approach described in Testcontainers [documentation](https://www.testcontainers.org/supported_docker_environment/continuous_integration/gitlab_ci/)? So in your case the provided example of `.gitlab-ci.yml` would look something like:

```
# DinD service is required for Testcontainers
services:
  - docker:dind

variables:
  # Instruct Testcontainers to use the daemon of DinD.
  DOCKER_HOST: "tcp://docker:2375"
  # Improve performance with overlayfs.
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2

test:
 image: maven:3-jdk-8
 stage: test
 script: mvn clean verify
```

Comment: yes this is exactly what I do. And in such case I get: "docker: command not found" in 'test' stage.

Comment: Why do you need `docker` command explicitly in the integration tests stage? Usually, testcontainers library requires just docker daemon, not the command itself. The containers are started with help of java code, not the `docker` command.

Comment: Without the docker command, how do you login to your registry?